# Creating randomly rotated and placed ellipses with background noise in python

Tags: python, ellipse

I am trying to generate an image with a randomly placed and rotated ellipse. Everything else is working as it should, however the ellipse is not rotating.

```
from PIL import ImageDraw, Image, ImageFilter
import math
import numpy as np
import random

#define build area
x_bound = int(input("X Resolution? (Pixel) "))
y_bound = int(input("Y resolution? (Pixel) "))


#define number of outputs
repetitions = int(input("How many output images would you like? "))
count = 0

#choose amount of bubbles
distortion = int(input("how many distorting circles would you like "))

while count != repetitions:
    img = Image.new("RGB", (x_bound, y_bound), color="White")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    #initialize randomness based on clock
    random.seed()


    # Generate a basic random colour, random RGB values 10-245
    R, G, B = random.randint(10, 245), random.randint(10, 245), random.randint(10, 245),

    for _ in range(0, distortion):
        # Choose RGB values for this circle
        r = R + random.randint(-10, 10)
        g = G + random.randint(-10, 10)
        b = B + random.randint(-10, 10)
        diam = random.randint(30, 90)
        x, y = random.randint(0, x_bound), random.randint(0, y_bound)

        draw.ellipse([x, y, x + diam, y + diam], fill=(r, g, b))

    # Blur the background a bit
    res = img.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(5))
    #img.show(res)

    # define shape bounds.
    # I don't want to have a 0 value for size, always moving in the positive direction
    x1 = random.randint(0, x_bound)    y1 = random.randint(0, y_bound)
    x2 = random.randint(x1, x_bound)
    y2 = random.randint(y1, y_bound)

    #commented line allows you to check coordinates, point of error check
    print(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    shape = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]

    # create ellipse image
    img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    img1.ellipse(shape, fill=None, outline="black")

    # rotate the ellipse image
    rotation_value = random.randint(0, 180)
    rotate = img.rotate(rotation_value)
    #img.show(rotate)
    # finding bounds of rotated figure
    angle = rotation_value * math.pi / 180

    # rotated coordinates of each of the four bounded corners
    x_prime_1 = -y1 * math.sin(angle) + x1 * math.cos(angle)
    y_prime_1 = y1 * math.cos(angle) + x1 * math.sin(angle)

    x_prime_2 = -y2 * math.sin(angle) + x2 * math.cos(angle)
    y_prime_2 = y2 * math.cos(angle) + x2 * math.sin(angle)

    # commented code line is to check coordinates of rotated shape for validity
    print(x_prime_1, y_prime_1, x_prime_2, y_prime_2)

    # start a counter, ensure that x coordinates fall within defined bounds
    x_count = 0

    if x_prime_1 < x_bound:
        x_count += 1
    if x_prime_1 > 0:
        x_count += 1
    if x_prime_2 < x_bound:
        x_count += 1
    if x_prime_2 > 0:
        x_count += 1

    # start a counter, ensure that y coordinates fall within defined bounds
    y_count = 0

    if y_prime_1 < y_bound:
        y_count += 1
    if y_prime_1 > 0:
        y_count += 1
    if y_prime_2 < y_bound:
        y_count += 1
    if y_prime_2 > 0:
        y_count += 1

    print(x_count), print(y_count)



    # ensure that both x and y coordinates fall within the defined area. Only then will it produce an 
    image.
    if y_count == 4:
        if x_count == 4:
            img.show()
            count += 1
```